# ImageMagick: -auto-orient is freezing

Tags: image, imagemagick, exif

System (`uname -a`):

```
Linux Inspiron-530s 4.4.0-97-generic #120-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 19 17:28:18 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

ImageMagick Version (`convert -version`):

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2017-07-31 
http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC Modules OpenMP
Delegates: bzlib cairo djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png rsvg tiff wmf x xml zlib
```

Running this freezes the shell:

`~$ convert image.jpg -auto-orient /tmp/Result.jpg`

This is the image in question, it has an EXIF orientation value of 6 (it's in a .zip file so nothing messes with the EXIF data):
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0YopyBgBXqNYXMwb3Z1bmp5dWs

**EDIT: Strange. Now it's working all of a sudden. Any idea how it frose in the first place?**

Comment: The image you posted has orientation=undefined. Try zipping your file and then put a link to the zip file. That way, the upload process won't change your meta data. Also what is your ImageMagick version and platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I'm an idiot.**

I was using this line inside a shell script and turns out I forgot to change the variable name of the file name while I was working on it. I was passing an uninitialized variable as the file...